Do I use the null article after "ohne" for a noun that is part of a longer phrase?
If I understand correctly, in many cases where in English we would say "without a [noun]," in German it would be "ohne [noun]," with no article. For example, "don't go outside without a coat" would be "gehen Sie nicht ohne Mantel nach draußen." However, I am not sure if this applies where the noun is part of a longer phrase. For example, I have these lines in English:

Should anyone dare to fight it without a big sword in their hands?


No tavern would be complete without the head of a deer on the wall.

I am not sure if in German the first line would be "... ohne ein großes Schwert in den Händen" or just "ohne großes Schwert in den Händen."
I am also wondering if this applies when there is an adjective in front of the noun, for example:

I would not go and fight it without a sharp blade.

Is it "ohne scharfe Klinge" or "ohne eine scharfe Klinge?"
This is related to this question as well as this one but differs in that I am asking about the use of the null article for a larger phrase, not just a single noun.

I suggest  that you provide a source for your working assumption so this can be specifically addressed. In my opinion, the indefinite article is nowhere wrong in your examples, it would only be omitted, since it does not contribute to the meaning.

There are several questions here discussing this issue, e.g. https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/74500/no-article-after-ohne-and-mit and https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61328/ohne-with-indefinite-articles and the answers suggest that the meaning is slightly different without an article. The problem is that they do not address any situation where there is anything beyond a single noun after "ohne."

Duplicate of https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/61328/ohne-with-indefinite-articles

This question is similar to: "ohne" with indefinite articles. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@tofro - I originally posted that question, and didn't accept the answer given because I wasn't convinced that it was valid. I posted my own, apparently half-baked, theory as well, but that doesn't seem to work either. Perhaps this issue deserves another discussion from a fresh perspective. In any case, as the OP pointed out, this question is about multiword noun phrases and I was asking about singe word nouns.

The reason I am asking about longer phrases is a) none of the existing questions or answers mention them at all and b) one answer from @tofro suggests that using ohne + null article refers to a broader concept, for example "ohne Mantel" is implying "without any warm clothing at all." I was not sure if a phrase like "head of a deer on the wall" was still generalizable to a broad concept, since it is more specific.

This question is similar to: No article after "ohne" and "mit". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@bakunin both my question and the answers already make clear that I am asking about the use of a null article in part of a longer phrase, not just a single noun as in that question. I have added the link to that question though.

@odduse_of_language: this my whole point: the answer is applicable to your problem because there is absolutely no difference.

@bakunin That is not what either of the people who provided answers here say and I am trusting their knowledge on this.

Let's try a few different attributes for the noun:
relative clause: impossible

*Ich kann mir nicht vorstellen, ohne Mensch, der mir beim Abwasch hilft, zu leben.

apposition: impossible

*ohne Million Follower, *ohne Toga, (ein) römisches Gewand

adjective: possible

ohne kurzärmliges Hemd, ?ohne scharfes Schwert

I like the explanation of the word after "ohne" being turned into an abstract concept. So while "kurzärmliges Hemd" feels like a single concept to me, but "scharfes Schwert" feels less so. DWDS can't distinguish singular from plural, and even less countable from uncountable, but try to compare the hits "ohne ADJ NOUN" to "ohne ein/eine ADJ NOUN". There are a lot of hits without article.
I feel like the "one" hypothesis from @HubertSchölnast 's answers fits very well to the examples.
prepositional clause: possible (see the examples at DWDS)

ohne Bewilligung von der tibetischen Seite her

und: possible

ohne Furcht und Tadel, ohne Anfang und Ende

your examples: So in all your examples you can leave out the article, although I think that I would not. I think, the more common a specific combination is, the more likely I am to drop the article.

The key is to understand that the German indefinite article »ein« (engl. a, an) is completely identical to the German numeral »ein« (engl. one):

indefinite article

What have you got in your bag? Is that a billiard ball? Or an orange?
No, there's an apple in my bag.


Was hast du da in deiner Tasche? Ist das eine Billardkugel? Oder eine Orange?
Nein, in meiner Tasche ist ein Apfel.


numeral

I saw you put some apples in your bag. How many did you take? I bet there are three apples in your bag.
No, there is one apple in my bag.


Ich habe gesehen, dass du ein paar Äpfel in deine Tasche gegeben hast. Wie viele hast du genommen? Ich wette, in deiner Tasche sind drei Äpfel.
Nein, in meiner Tasche ist ein Apfel.



And this is true for all genders and all cases. So, when ever we use the article »ein« (engl.: a, an), then we always also have the numeral meaning of »ein« (engl.: one) in mind. And when it makes no sense to say one, then we use the word »ohne« without »ein«.

No article when the noun is a singular-only noun.

Laura sah Jürgen ohne Hass, aber auch ohne Liebe an.
Laura looked at Jürgen without hatred, but also without love.
Sebastian trank seinen Kaffe ohne Milch und ohne Zucker.
Sebastian drank his coffee without milk and without sugar.


Article is possible but still unusual for countable items


Paul lief ohne Mantel durch den Schneesturm.
Paul lief ohne einen Mantel durch den Schneesturm.

Paul was running through the snowstorm without a coat.

Here the article is possible, because there is a plural form of »der Mantel« (»die Mäntel«), but since you usually don't wear two or more coats at the same time, you always use the singular form in such a sentence, and then it's very similar to a singular-only noun. Also in English you usually don't say, that he run without one coat through the snowstorm.

But: If there is a attribute between »ohne« and the noun, then it's better to use the article:


Sollte es jemand wagen, sich ihm ohne großes Schwert in der Hand entgegenzustellen?
Sollte es jemand wagen, sich ihm ohne ein großes Schwert in der Hand entgegenzustellen?

Should anyone dare to fight it without a big sword in their hands?

The version »ohne großes Schwert« uses big swords similar to a category like coats. The version without article means just any big sword. But when you use an attribute then the thing in the fighters hand is not just a sword, but a big sword. The attribute makes is more specific. And this justifies the usage of an article, even if it's an indefinite article.
Compare it to the version without attribute:


Sollte es jemand wagen, sich ihm ohne Schwert in der Hand entgegenzustellen?
Sollte es jemand wagen, sich ihm ohne ein Schwert in der Hand entgegenzustellen?

Should anyone dare to fight it without a sword in their hands?

Also here are 1 and 2 possible, but I would tend to use version 1 here (»ohne Schwert«), while I would prefer version 2 if there is an extra attribute (»ohne ein großes Schwert«).


